# How to get value from ajax php (can't get)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Page 1 : index.php

script ajax

```
<script>               
function fcall(clusters) {

var clusters = document.getElementById("clusters").value;
var request = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "chart.php",   
        data: {clusters: clusters}
        });
        request.done( function( msg ) {
        $("#page").html(msg); 
        });
}
 </script>
```

script php

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tree_hie GROUP BY no_cluster asc") or die(mysql_error());
           while ($data1=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
           $clusters = $data1['no_cluster'];


  $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tree_hie where no_cluster = '$clusters'") or die(mysql_error());
             while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {



 <input type="button" id="clusters" name="clusters" onclick="fcall(<?php $data1['no_cluster']; ?>);" value="<?php echo $clusters; ?>">

    }} /* for while

    <div id="page">
    </div>
```

page 2 chart.php

```
$clusters = $_GET['clusters']."tez<br>";
echo $clusters."tez";
```

I have that code ..

My problem ..

and the output is link, example

*cluster 1*

*cluster 2* ..... etc

```
if i click button 'cluster 1', should on div page display 1 
if i click button 'cluster 2' should on div page display 2 ... 

BUT .. 

if i click button 'cluster 1', on div page display 1 
if i click button 'cluster 2' on div page display 1 too , 
still can't get value ..
```

may you know how to fixed it ?

Comment: Whatever come in "msg" that you have to show us. then only we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two button with the same id. Pass the event object in the function call

```
<input type="button" id="clusters" name="clusters" onclick="fcall(event);" value="<?php echo $clusters; ?>">
```

and use

```
function fcall(event) {
var clusters = event.target.value;
  ....
}
```